# $a,b,r,s$ are coprime such that $a^2+b^2=r^2$ and $a^2-b^2=s^2$. Which of the numbers are odd?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, parity

$a,b,r,s$ are coprime such that $a^2+b^2=r^2$ and $a^2-b^2=s^2$. I’m trying to show that $a, r, s$ is odd and $b$ is even.

If we add the equations, we get $2a^2=r^2+s^2$. Hence $r^2 + s^2$ is even. The square of number is even/odd iff the number is even/odd. Either $r^2$ and $s^2$ are both even or both odd since their sum is even. Thus $r$ and $s$ are both odd since they are coprime.

I’m only able to show that either $a$ is even and $b$ is odd or $a$ is odd and $b$ is even. Any hints are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean with coprime here ? That both triples $(a,b,r)$ and $(b,s,a)$ must be primitive ?

Comment: Hint : If we have a primitive triple $(a,b,c)$ satisfying $a^2+b^2=c^2$ , then $c$ cannot be even because then both $a$ and $b$ have to be odd (they cannot be both even) , but then $a^2+b^2\equiv 2\mod 4$ , hence cannot be a perfect square.

Comment: @Peter Cool. So since $a^2=s^2+b^2$, it follows that $a$ is odd. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Hint . An odd square is $1$ more than a multiple of $4.$ So if $r^2$ and $s^2$ are odd squares & if  $a^2=(r^2+s^2)/2$ and $b^2=(r^2-s^2)/2$ then ..........

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Nice hint! Thanks. $a^2=(4k_1+4k_2+2)/2=2(k_1+k_2)+1$ so $a$ is odd. Similarly $b^2=(4k_1-4k_2)/2=2(k_1-k_2)$ so $b$ is even